# Zero-shot out-of-distribution text classification

Tags: nlp, text-classification, zero-shot-learning

I'm building out a pipeline that would allow me to filter out text based on whether or not the text belongs to any of the classes I've defined.

I feel like one (albeit naive) approach would simply be to embed both the text and the text representing the class, and apply a distance function to both, discarding the sample if the distance is over some threshold.

Is this feasible in a zero-shot setting? If so, how should I go about figuring out the threshold? If not, what (if any) methods could be used in a zero-shot setting?

Note: I'm not looking for any methods that require additional data outside of the sample and the classes themselves.